# Are there any rules specifically governing/restricting magic item slots for animal companions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, animal-companions

Animal companions can have barding and horses in particular have access to magical horseshoes, but are there any rules stopping me from making custom magic items for other possible slots?

For example: Magic collars for wolves and dogs could act like rings and amulets. Magic caparisons for horses could act like magic cloaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Pathfinder rules [only explicitly state the slots available for humanoid creatures](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Items-on-the-Body).  However, there are two possible leads on an answer - [this Paizo thread quotes an old 3.5 "Rules of the Game" article](http://paizo.com/forums/dmtz30t7?Animal-Companions-and-Magic-Item-Slots#5) allows up to 12 slots, but [the ruling in Living Greyhawk games was](http://paizo.com/forums/dmtz30t7?Animal-Companions-and-Magic-Item-Slots#13) only slotless, animal specific, barding, and amulet (collar).  I personally would go with the latter but I hate Christmas tree syndrome.

Comment: Down with Christmas tree syndrome!

Answer (score 11):

At some point since this question was asked, Pazio released a splat book that includes all the slots for all the different kinds of Animal Companions.

[Source](https://aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?Name=Magic%20Item%20Slots&Category=Companions%20and%20Familiars)

Avian
Armor, belt, chest (saddle), eyes, head, headband, neck, ring, wrist

Biped (claws)
Armor, belt, chest, eyes, head, headband, neck, ring, shoulders, wrist

Biped (hands)
All item slots

Piscine
Belt, chest (saddle), eyes

Quadruped (claws)
Armor, belt (saddle), chest, eyes, head, headband, neck, shoulders, wrist

Quadruped (hooves)
Armor, belt (saddle), chest, eyes, feet (horseshoes), head, headband, neck, shoulders

Quadruped (short legs)
Armor, eyes, head, headband, neck, shoulders

Quadruped (other)
armor, belt (saddle), chest, eyes, head, headband, neck, shoulders

Serpentine
Belt, eyes, headband

Unusual (Plant and Vermin)
Belt, eyes

Comment: I've edited the answer to reference material from a more recent source; I hope you don't mind. Your original answer seems to have been based on the *Animal Archive* released in 2013; I updated it to match the *Ultimate Wilderness* book released in 2017 instead. (The animals originally listed under "saurian" seem to have been recategorized among "quadruped (short legs)" and "quadruped (other)".) I also included an excerpt of the quote that introduces the list, and changed the list to use bullet points.

Answer (score 4):

Something to remember is that an [Amulet of Mighty Fists](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-mighty-fists) specifically states "This amulet grants an enhancement bonus of +1 to +5 on attack and damage rolls with unarmed attacks and natural weapons." It also lets you add weapon special properties to unarmed and natural attacks. Animals have Natural weapons, so it would stand to reason than any animal would be able to use such an item. The problem with animals and some items is that they cannot (for obvious reasons) activate magical items, so any items they could use would have to be of the "always on when worn" variety. You could argue that an item had been specifically designed to be activated by an animal, but you would need to use one of the animal's tricks to teach it how to use it, and then command the animal to turn it on or off.

Also note that unless your playing in a world where Druids and Wizards are constantly outfitting all of their animals with these things, finding magical equipment for an Animal is likely to be a rare thing. Players may need to commission the construction of these specialty magical items, something that requires time (finding a person who can create a masterwork item of the required type, finding the person who can enchant it, negotiating with these people, plus the time required to craft such things) and raw resources the players may or may not not have. If your Druid/Ranger wants magical items for their pets, this could easily become a quest in and of itself.

I do like the 12-slot list given by mxyzplk. I think it would give a character many options for outfitting his animal companion.